# How to get relative path of the file that is exist in project folder in .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to get a file path that is there in project file.

I tried

```
var path = @"Helper\automationJson.json"
```

but this getting the file from `bin/debug` as `C:\AutomationActivityTrace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Helper\automationJson.json`

Also tried

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, subfolder name, filename);
```

and many more but I am not getting exactly what I want.

I need the path as `C:\AutomationActivityTrace\Helper\automationJson.json`

Can anyone help?!

Comment: Use var path= Path.Combine(new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName, "automationJson.js");

Comment: A few things. One, is it automationJson **.json** or **.js**? Two, how is this code being called -- from a console app, a web app controller, other? Also, what does `Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Helper", "automationJson.json")` give you?

Comment: @mrblewog ,its a json file and console app ,i got  C:\AutomationActivityTrace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Helper\automationJson.json  for Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Helper", "automationJson.json")

Comment: @Rufw91 i got C:\AutomationActivityTrace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\automationJson.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Assumption**: your app needs to read this **specific** file and the file is present at **build time**.

You'll need to copy it to the `bin` folder as part of your build. This is done in your `csproj` file using `CopyToOputputDirectory`.

For example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <!-- other stuff -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Helper\*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now when you build the project, say with `dotnet build`, you should get a copy in `C:\AutomationActivityTrace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Helper\automationJson.json`

The solutions involving `AppContext.BaseDirectory` should then find the file, for example `Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Helper", "automationJson.json")`

Comment: `AppContext.BaseDirectory` is not in the bin folder for me while running the application in IDE